# How does Bungeecord/Lilypad send players to other servers

Tags: java, minecraft, bungeecord

So I previously asked a question if you can send a client that's on a ServerSocket to a different Server. But now, I'm asking how are the players for minecraft sent from server to server using Bungeecord and/or Lilypad. I know that LilyPad uses proxies and that stuff, but how are the players, when connected to the Bungeecord/Lilypad server, sent to a hub/spawn and/or to other servers, for example a survival server and a creative server. You can find servers like this on servers that have networks. I know that Treasure wars uses lilypad, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question. Both Bungeecord and LilyPad are proxy server networks.

Though a server cannot redirect the client to another server without permission, the server *can* connect to another server (meaning the first server is a proxy) and send back that server's messages to the client. As the first server is, in essence, also a client to the second server, the first server can switch connections at any desired point.

In other words, the Minecraft client does not switch connections at any point. The IP of the server to which the Minecraft client is connected never changes, and it is that of the proxy. However, what does change is the server to which the proxy is connected. If the client sends some message to the proxy stating that it wishes to go to the hub, the proxy then disconnects from whatever server it is currently connected to, connects to the hub, and sends back to the Minecraft client whatever messages the hub responds with.

This is my understanding based on a quick search.

However, if the Minecraft *client* was modded as well, it would be possible to have a similar network without the need for a proxy like so:

- Client interacts with the server in such a way (maybe the player walks into a portal) as to trigger some server-switching action.
- The server recognizes this interaction and, as both it and the client are modded, knows how to respond. The response is simply the sending of a message to the client, saying, "Switch to a different server. Here is the IP: (Insert IP here)"
- The client receives the message from the server and, by its own will, disconnects from the current server and reconnects to the new one.

Comment: Ok, That is a great answer, and Thank you for replying.

Comment: And now I am banned from asking questions ._.